# drawing a scatter plot from two matrices

Tags: r, plot

I would like to draw a scatter plot from two matrices:

the first matix contains my X-values on the diagram and has only one column.

```
   [,1]
[1,]  3
[2,]  5
[3,]  8
...   ...
```

Matrix B has n columns and they are my Y-Values in the diagram:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] ...
[1,]  80   85   25  ...
[2,]  42   35   57  ...
[3,]  81   52   39  ...
...  ...
```

first row in Matrix b belongs to first row in matrix a.

I want to draw the scatter plot from this two matrices, for example for the value `3` on the X-axis I want to have points on the `80,85,25,..` Y-axis

How can I do this job?

Comment: You can use `matplot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Roland's comment:

```
matplot(a, b, type="p")   # "p" is the default but I put it in to highlight the possibility of using "l" or "b"
```

.... does exactly what you asked for: column of X versus columns of Y.